# How to "lie" to mediaquery? How to fake the width of window?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Im developing responsive sites, and you all know its a bit comfortless to manually shrink the window of browser (moreover, Firefox doesnt let me do it after a value). So I decided to write a jQuery "plugin" to shrink the area with - or + buttons.

Once I wrote this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var doResizing = function(increaseWith) {
        if ($('#xxxx').length == 0) {
            $('body').css('margin', 0).css('padding', 0);
            $('body > *').wrapAll('<div id="xxxx" /></div>');

            $('#xxxx').css('background-color', 'red')
                .css('overflow', 'scroll')
                .css('padding', 0)
                .css('margin', 0)
                .css('position', 'absolute')
                .width('100%');
        }
        $('#xxxx').height(parseInt($(window).height()) + 'px').width(parseInt($('#xxxx').width())+increaseWith + 'px');
    }

    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 45) {
            doResizing (-10);
        }

        if (e.which == 43) {
            doResizing (+10);
        }
    });
});
```

its OK for checking, but even with the correct definition of media query, it wont buy it. Then how to say to the mediaquery that width has changed, without actually resizing the window?

Comment: *Note : if you're using chrome, you can emulate a smaller screen within the Developer tools*

Comment: What's wrong with just, resizing the window itself may I ask? :X

Comment: because ifs still easier to press + or - instead of for touching the mouse :)

Comment: Using Ctrl + Shift + M in FireFox isn't good enough?

Comment: oh I didnt even know that, but that way no scrolling vertically

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that the media query is still seeing the page at full width. You could adapt your code slightly to take the page and embed it into an iframe and resize the iFrame:

```
var doResizing = function (increaseWith) {
     if ($('#xxxx').length == 0) {
            $('body').css('margin', 0).css('padding', 0);
            $('body > *').wrapAll('<iframe id="xxxx" src="' + window.Location + '" /></iframe>');
            $('#xxxx').css('background-color', 'red').css('overflow', 'scroll').css('padding', 0).css('margin', 0).css('position', 'absolute').width('100%');
    }
    $('#xxxx').height(parseInt($(window).height()) + 'px').width(parseInt($('#xxxx').width()) + increaseWith + 'px');
}
```

Comment: Doing this removed all the styling from my page. Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 9):

Chrome has an inbuilt function for that:

[image: Google Chrome Rocks!]

If you don't see the setting go to:

`Settings > Devices > [Choose your devices]`

Comment: I only see Console and Search in my chrome. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

In Firefox - `Tools / Web Developer / Responsive  Design View`

Or just hit `Ctrl + Shift + M`

This will let you get down to small view port sizes, it also drops the scroll bar to small, and overlay -  so you don't have that to deal with too. ( it's there, just very small, like a mobile )

Create preset sizes, switch orientation - well ace.

Apologies, just seen this in a comment too , anyways ..

Answer (score 3):

There is a add-on for Firefox that does that: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/more-display-resolutions/

Comment: +1, Sounded good to me too, didn't know this was for firefox.