# How to make bootstrap non responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On mobile screen I want Bootstrap to act as if it is on a desktop display. The contents should go out of the screen. I have tried removing this line

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

It is still fully mobile responsive. I tried doing

```
.container{
 min-width:900px;
}
```

This gets me to where I want as the contents overflow to fit the 900px width. However, divs which I have given `class="col-md-6 col-12"` on mobile screen still acts as if it is in a smaller width than 900px by taking the entire column instead of getting divided into `col-md-6` and `col-md-6`. Is there a way for me to override this responsive behavior? I know that I can just do `col-6` as a class but there is a long explanation why I cannot do that for my project.

Comment: this [iframe solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572732/how-to-lie-to-mediaquery-how-to-fake-the-width-of-window) might work for you

Comment: How about adding a <style> block to your page with custom overrides to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the iframe solution after I am back from work and let you know.

Comment: Tom, I don't know how it's done but I will look into it as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=900, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Pass the width where I have entered '900' for example. it will make the bootstrap page not responsive after 900px to 0px;

It will work.

Answer (score 2):

Use the class `.col-xs-*` instade of `.col-sm-*` or `.col-md-*` or `.col-lg-*`